# nginx redirect not including query string

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I've defined a new server block with a regex match and redirect:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~^homersimpson.(?<domain>.*)$;
  rewrite ^ $scheme://$domain/apply?ref=thesimpsons redirect;
}
```

But the URL after curling is without the query string?

```
curl -w "%{url_effective}\n" -I -L -s -S https://homersimpson.domain.com -o /dev/null 
https://homersimpson.domain.com/
```

How do i rewrite the url with a query string?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~^homersimpson.(?<domain>.*)$;
  return 301 $scheme://$domain/apply?ref=thesimpsons;
}
```